# Xpath Selenium VBA for a Check Box

Tags: html, selenium

I'm trying to identify a check box to tick. But I'm having trouble with the xpath.

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="display: inline-block;">
<input name="PriceRealization" class="custom-control-input" id="check-7012949" type="checkbox" value="TRUE">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="check-7012949"> Include Price Realization</label>
</div>
```

and this is what I have

```
.FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='custom-control custom-checkbox'][following-sibling::div[1][.//*[contains(text(),'Include Price Realization')]]]").Click
```

but it is finding the wrong chekbox (another one with the same class) but different text.
I'm really bad with xpath and can't see where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following **xpath** to select input checkbox.

```
//div[.//label[normalize-space(.)='Include Price Realization']]/input
```

**Code**:

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[.//label[normalize-space(.)='Include Price Realization']]/input").Click
```

Comment: Thanks KunduK
That gave me the error
Element not visible, cannot click on element.

Comment: @MichaelLiew : You need to provide some wait until element is visible.put some wait before interacting the element.

Comment: Thanks again, I already had a stop on the code (as I was debugging it) so the element was visible.
what does the normalize-space(.) Section do?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error

I managed to figure it out

```
.FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='custom-control custom-checkbox']//label[contains(text(),'Include Price Realization')]").Click
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try
driver.FindElementByXpath("//label[@class="custom-control-label][text()=Include Price Realization]")